# How can I filter data based on date?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have downloaded stock price data using `tidyquant` package in R. This company's financial year ends on 31st March every year. So, I want to filter data only for 31st March for all the available years. The data is available from 1-Jan-2013 to 1-Feb-2023. Out of them, I want to keep only the datapoints, where the dates are as follows:

```
31-Mar-2013;
31-Mar-2014;
31-Mar-2015;
31-Mar-2016;
31-Mar-2017;
31-Mar-2018;
31-Mar-2019;
31-Mar-2020;
31-Mar-2021;
31-Mar-2022
```

How can I apply such filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
your_data_frame$DATE_COLUMN <- dmy(your_data_frame$DATE_COLUMN)
dplyr::filter(your_data_frame, month(DATE_COLUMN) == 3, day(DATE_COLUMN == 31)
```

Given that March 31 will sometimes fall on a weekend, it might make sense to pull the last day of March instead.

```
your_data_frame %>%
  filter(month(DATE_COLUMN) == 3) %>%
  group_by(year = year(DATE_COLUMN)) %>%
  slice_max(DATE_COLUMN) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Indeed, in some of the years, the last working day of the financial year was not 31st March, but 27 or 28th March.